# Add bookmark programmatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a bookmark from my application using [Browser.saveBookmark](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Browser.html#saveBookmark%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
  protected void saveBookmark(String title, String url){
    Browser.saveBookmark(this, title, url);
  }
```

The window where the user can modify my title and press "Save bookmark" displays correctly, but when I press save, the browser closes unexpectedly

```
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.webkit.WebIconDatabase$EventHandler.<init>(WebIconDatabase.java:46)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.webkit.WebIconDatabase$EventHandler.<init>(WebIconDatabase.java:46)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.webkit.WebIconDatabase.<init>(WebIconDatabase.java:43)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at android.webkit.WebIconDatabase.getInstance(WebIconDatabase.java:293)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.browser.Bookmarks.addBookmark(Bookmarks.java:136)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at com.android.browser.AddBookmarkPage$SaveBookmarkRunnable.run(AddBookmarkPage.java:136)
12-28 18:07:20.864: E/AndroidRuntime(560):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

I'm calling this action from the UI thread, so I don't know what's happening.

I've tried using the [WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS)

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.browser.permission.WRITE_HISTORY_BOOKMARKS" />
```

but nothing changes.

I've tested this on an emulator and a Galaxy S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this might be a bug in earlier versions of Android

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11291

Comment: Thanks, good to know. Do you know a workaround to add a bookmark?

Comment: I don't, but read the comments of the issue.  They'd be there if there is one.